# WCF Service Application returns 404 using WebGet

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, http-status-code-404

I created just the most basic WCF Service Application to do some prototyping, but I can't get the WebGet implementation to work.

Here's my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/rest/{value}")]
    string Test(string value);
}
```

Here's the implementation:

```
public string Test(string value)
{
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

But if I go to http://localhost:3305/rest/Hello in my browser, I get a 404.  I'm using the  VS 2008 webserver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your missing the actual service name.

http://localhost:3305/yourservicename.svc/rest/Hello

Comment: Yup - don't forget the SVC-file in your URL !

Comment: That worked.  I also had to change the ending binding to be "webHttpBinding" and create an endpoint behavior that specified <webHttp /> -- probably obvious misses to people familiar with this stuff, but not easily discoverable for people new to WCF.  Thanks again.

Comment: What did you change inside the Web.Config in order to get it to work with webHttpBinding?

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);

public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
         config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
         config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        //config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
```