# WCF method's breakpoint not being hit

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, query-string, querystringparameter

I am new to WCF and I am building a service to do CRUD operations. I have created a new void method that takes two parameters. I have set a breakpoint and in debugging mode I have pasted this URL:

```
http://localhost:55152/WcfDataService.svc/AddNewNote()?ParamNoteTitle='dfdfdf'&ParamNoteText='dfdfdfdf'
```

This is my code:

```
 [WebGet]
    public void AddNewNote(string ParamNoteTitle, string ParamNoteText)
    {
        //My hardcoded values for now...
        int ParentID = 8879;
        int JobID = 1000088150;
        int ContactID = 309;
        Guid UserID = Guid.NewGuid();
        string RelatedType = "Advertiser Contact";
        bool IsShared = true;

        tblNote N = new tblNote
        {
          NotesTitle = ParamNoteTitle,
          NotesText = ParamNoteText,
          ParentID = ParentID,
          ContactID = ContactID,
          JobID = JobID,
          UserID = UserID,
          GroupID = null,
          RelatedType = RelatedType,
          IsShared = IsShared
        };
        this.CurrentDataSource.tblNotes.Add(N);
        this.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();

    }
```

I am getting a 404 error. Is there a problem with my query string/URL?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the service itself is running correctly by pasting this URL in your browser:

```
http://localhost:55152/WcfDataService.svc
```

If so, I would recommend you to have a look at this similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802518/invoking-wcf-service-method-through-a-browser).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Communal - Betc I have other methods for retrieving data so I know the root URL is working. I will look at the link you provided.

Comment: Here are some more links to help you out: [Link#1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1777307.aspx/1), [Link#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848198/wcf-service-application-returns-404-using-webget). And if it's hosted in a MVC App [Link#3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/87fcf70f-eda7-4ad8-b24f-b32be6ed932a/) and [Link#4](http://forums.asp.net/p/1662944/4341154.aspx#4341154)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my method type to IQueryable and calling a method to retrieve the new row with my ID after the insert. I originally wanted to return an integer or bool so in my Javascript I can handle success or failure by looking at the return value.

```
 [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<vw_Note> AddNewNote(string ParamNoteTitle, string ParamNoteText)
    {
        //My hardcoded values for now...
        int ParentID = 8879;
        int JobID = 1000088150;
        int ContactID = 309;
        Guid UserID = new Guid("8b0e303a-68aa-49a5-af95-d994e2bdd5ac");
        Guid NoteID = Guid.NewGuid();
        string RelatedType = "Advertiser Contact";
        bool IsShared = true;

        tblNote N = new tblNote
        {
            NotesID = NoteID,
            NotesTitle = ParamNoteTitle,
            NotesText = ParamNoteText,
            ParentID = ParentID,
            ContactID = ContactID,
            JobID = JobID,
            UserID = UserID,
            GroupID = null,
            RelatedType = RelatedType,
            IsShared = IsShared
        };
        try
        {
            this.CurrentDataSource.tblNotes.Add(N);
            this.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();
            return GetNoteByID(NoteID);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return GetNoteByID(NoteID);
        }

    }
```

As you can see it will return a set of data. I was stuck on how to handle inserting data using WCF and then responding to a client request but I managed to solve it. Thanks anyway!